# mailman list: subscribe without sending user to another page

Tags: mailman

Is there any way I can have users sign up for my mailman list *without* having them redirected to the mailman list page?

A simple form on my site at the top right corner of every page works fine.  It is simple and elegant.

```
<FORM Method=POST ACTION="http://xxxxxxx/mailman/subscribe/xxxxxxxx">
email:<INPUT type="Text" name="email" size="30" value=""><br />
<INPUT type="Submit" name="email-button" value="Subscribe"><br />
</FORM>
```

But, it takes a potential customer away from my ecommerce site.  A horrible tragedy!!

Yes, I suppose I could tweak the subscription results page in settings thusly:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Subscription Results</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
 content="1;url=http://www.example.com/mypage.html">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>   <<thanks tigertech.net for that idea
```

...to redirect them back to my site.  But that still would not keep them on the page they were at when they clicked the subscribe button.

I need a click to subcscribe, then "Thanks!" in the same spot on my site without leaving the page they are currently on.  (The sign up form will be on all pages of the site.) Then they'll get the confirmation email.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Process the data (email addresses and, optionally, user names) on the server hosting the form and have the results **emailed** to your Mailman list's "subscribe" address, formatted as a subscription request.

Mailman would then pick up from there with any confirmation process you have established for the target list.

Typically, the page containing your subscription form would redisplay after submitting. If there were no errors in creating and sending the email, it would make sense to display a message at that point telling users what they can expect to see next (probably the confirmation email).

You don't say what scripting languages are available to you on the e-commerce server, but most support the ability to generate email.